# WPF adding Icon to windows cause Property Error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Here is the exact error I got.
[image]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m12122/1237235885-clip-36kb.png))</sub>

The favicon.ico has been added in the project as a resource and I have set to "Resource" the Build Action.
[image]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m12122/1237236030-clip-6kb.png))</sub>

I found some solution that require to add some code. My question is why I can't do it with the Visual Studio Interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with close.bmp. I renamed it to close-image.bmp, and it fixed it. But right now, I tryed to rename it into close.bmp again, and today it works. Seems to be a problem with solution... Read this discussion:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswpfdesigner/thread/b03061e5-5500-442f-9c88-a6d82f97c2b7

Also, your settings are right. You need to include it and make 'Build Action: Resource'

Answer (score 0):

I just tried in Visual Studio 2008 SP 1 and it worked. I dragged the file into the project, and I was simply able to type "favicon.ico" in the property pane.

Are you sure it's at the root level of your application? If you have it in a subfolder in the project it will require the full relative path (like "icons\favicon.ico").

Answer (score 0):

If your icon is under a folder, have you included the folder name?

[1237239323-clip-25kb http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1237239323-clip-25kb.png](http://clip2net.com/page/m0/727896)